# Separate input and output in console application?

Tags: c#, multithreading, input, console, output

I'm making a console application in c#. And i'm having an issue where it overwrites what i'm typing.. I have it running on two threads.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Grab Input
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(getInput)).Start();
    }

    public static void getInput()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string command = System.Console.ReadLine();
            handleCommand(command);
        }
    }

    public static void handleCommand(string command)
    {
        //Do whatever with the command
    }
}
```

However, Now if i do

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Anything");
```

If i'm already writing input, it will put "Anything" right in the middle of my input.. I'm just wondering how to separate input and output in a console application :3

Any help would be awesome. Thanks in advance..

Example Issue:
[image: Example Issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm just wondering how to separate input and output in a console application :3

There isn't really a way to do this in a console application.

If you want full control, including "separation" of input and output, a GUI is an appropriate way to go.  This would allow you to keep your input control(s) completely separated from any output being displayed to the user.

Comment: To build on this, the OP might want to check out Curses Sharp to build a Console GUI. http://sourceforge.net/projects/curses-sharp/

Comment: @JustinNiessner Though curses isn't thread safe, either... You'd still need to do some trickery using Curses Sharp if you wanted to use it from multiple threads...

Comment: It would at least give the OP a way to position the text separate from the input...if done properly.

Comment: @Justin Niessner, Is there any documentation on Curses Sharp?.. I can't seem to find any..

Comment: @thefiscster510 It's a basic "curses" API implementation - so reading the ncurses docs will give you an idea of how it works: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/  Note that it's basically just a wrapper around the Console class, so you could just use SetCursorPosition, etc, yourself (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx)  That being said, this isn't going to solve your original problem, though - you'd need to handle thread safety yourself, which means making your own IO buffers to avoid the overlapping text.

Comment: @thefiscster510 Creating a simple GUI app would likely be far simpler, since Control.BeginInvoke or Dispatcher.BeginInvoke makes the thread safety issues quite a bit simpler than trying to manage this yourself within a console app (where there is no synchronization context)

Comment: @Reed Copsey, As far as IO Buffers go, how would i go about doing that? Also, This would not need to be thread safe.. I was just using a thread because I thought it would be simpler to separate the input / output.

Comment: @thefiscster510 I'd probably make a separate thread, with its own synchronization context, and marshal all IO calls to it.  That way, you'd never overlap - it'd be a pain, though.  Making a GUI is easier, and probably nicer for the user, too